How to merge 2D vectors in excel while adding duplicate values?
Say I have the following arrays in Excel:



Item
Quantity




Apples
3


Bananas
2


Coconuts
5






Item
Quantity




Oranges
3


Pears
1


Apples
9






Item
Quantity




Bananas
4


Oranges
2


Strawberries
8



What can I do to merge them all together and add up the quantities for any duplicate I have?
The result would have to be something like this:



Item
Quantity




Apples
12


Bananas
6


Coconuts
5


Oranges
5


Pears
1


Strawberries
8



I'm not sure what I could be doing for that, VSTACK is close but not quite. I don't have access to scripting as I'm using the free version of Excel from browser.

Do you have access to GROUPBY?

Unfortunately I don't

If applicable use GROUPBY() as already mentioned above else use MMULT() or MAP() or BYROW()


=LET(
     α, VSTACK(Table1,Table2,Table3),
     GROUPBY(TAKE(α,,1), TAKE(α,,-1),SUM,,0))


Or, using MAP()
=LET(
     α, VSTACK(Table1,Table2,Table3),
     δ, TAKE(α,,1),
     φ, UNIQUE(δ),
     HSTACK(φ, MAP(φ, LAMBDA(x, SUM((x=δ)*TAKE(α,,-1))))))


Or, Using MMULT()
=LET(
     α, VSTACK(Table1,Table2,Table3),
     δ, TAKE(α,,1),
     φ, UNIQUE(δ),
     HSTACK(φ, MMULT(N(φ=TOROW(δ)),TAKE(α,,-1))))


